# Monotouch: UINavigationController, override initWithRootViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, controller, xamarin.ios, rootview

How is it possible to override the constructor for UINavigationController for passing in a rootViewController?

I would have a method like the following in Objective-C:

```
-(id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController
{
    UIViewController *fakeController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (self = [super initWithRootViewController:fakeController]) {

      self.fakeRootViewController = fakeController;

      rootViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

      [self pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO];
    } 
    return self;
}
```

Thank you in advance. Regards.

P.S This snippet of code has been taken from [Change the root view controller](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/changing-a-uinavigationcontroller%E2%80%99s-root-view-controller/)

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your replies. I was interested in the previous snippet of code because it's particular interesting.

@Geoff Norton:  Maybe I'll never use your solution but I find it amazing anyway...

My attempt is to create a sort of UINavigationViewController that acts as a template. In particular, the UINavigationController initially has a loginView (it could be a sort of rootviewcontroller). Then when logging in, I could have two type of views: main and secondary views. The former are at the same level of the login view (they could be a sort of rootviewcontrollers). The latter are pushed above the first ones. You can navigate through the normal UInavigationController stack or by means of a toolbar. The toolbar loads only main view.

Is it possible to do this with a UINavigationController?

Thank you again. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible but you shouldn't do it.  According to Apple the UINavigationController is ["not designed for subclassing".](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  If you insist on doing this:

```
public YourNavController : UINavigationController {
    [Export ("initWithRootViewController:")]
    public YourNavController (UIViewController vc) {
      UIViewController fc = new UIViewController ();
      Handle = Messaging.intptr_objc_msgSend_intptr (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("initWithRootViewController:"), fc.Handle);
      FakeRootViewController = fc;
      vc.NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = true;
      PushViewController (vc, false);
    }
}
```

Something close to that should work.

Answer (score 2):

Like Geoff Norton pointed out, you are not supposed to subclass UINavigationController.

I have insisted on doing this myself a few times, just to find out that there are bugs that pop up every once in a while that have no logical explanation.    When you Google those up, the answer invariably is "You should have not subclassed UINavigationController".